# copy a user directory from one to another workstation on a same domain

Tags: user-accounts, domain, migration

Please advise me how to copy a user directory from one workstation to another on the same domain. Does a normal copy and paste would do?? Because, whatever the article I'm finding does not say anything about changing to another work station on a same domain

What I need: to transfer files from a pc to another by adding domain to the new pc. both pc's are under domain and data stored locally in pc (not roaming).

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: A domain admin account is required to do this.  If you don't have one it's a show stopper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very simply with the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-files-settings-from-another-computer#1TC=windows-7) program. However, you will require an Administrator account to run the software correctly.

The software is extremely simple to use:

- Run Windows Easy Transfer on 'old' computer.
- Select your transfer method then 'This is my old computer'.
- Choose accounts/files to transfer.
- The software will then go through and search for files/accounts to back up.
- Select required files to transfer and hit `Done`.

To transfer back, simply pick 'This is my new computer', and choose which account you want to restore.

Comment: thank you for this. I didn't thought of this simple thing actually. I will test it out. once again thank you.